# What is the shortest way to read the entire contents of a file to standard output?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking for the best way to read the contents of a file into `std::cout` in standard C++. I don't care about formatting anything I just want the raw contents to be printed. What would be the shortest way to do this?

Comment: `std::copy` could work.

Comment: You mean read the contents of the file and *write* it to `std:cout`?

Comment: @Gabe Yes that's what I mean.

Comment: "I'm looking for the best way" ... "What would be the shortest way" - so by best, you mean shortest (i.e. most concise)?

Comment: @Cornstalks Let me fix that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One (fairly) short possibility would be something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    std::ifstream in(argv[1]); // error checking omitted for now
    std::cout << in.rdbuf();
}
```

This isn't the most efficient if the file is really long, but for almost anything you'd normally want to display on `stdout`, it'll normally be fine. If you're going to feed the output to some other program, and want something faster for huge files, you could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::ifstream in(argv[1], std::ios::binary);
    static char buffer[1024*1024*8];

    while (in.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)), in.gcount()!=0)
        std::cout.write(buffer, in.gcount());
}
```

Comment: Bonus points for also including the most efficient...

Comment: Thank you guys for all the answers.

Comment: Actually, I would expect using the stream buffer approach to be the most efficient approach because the copy _could_ use a back door into the stream buffers and directly manipulating the buffers, i.e., `memcpy()`ing memory from one buffer to the other (which could, BTW, also be done when `std::copy()`ing stream buffers: my implementation actually does that (if I recall correctly; I'm not sure if I just prototyped it or if the code is on the version which is still available).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: In theory, I completely agree. In fact, it seems to depend somewhat on the implementation though.

Comment: ***TWO*** lines of code??!? Bloatware.

Comment: @Casey: Perhaps. I never was particularly great at code golf stuff...

Comment: My belief is that an OS call would be more efficient, after all, part of an OS's job is file handling.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: My experience is that you can often beat an OS call. I haven't re-tested it recently, but at least at one time (NT 4, Win2K) my file copying code beat Windows' `CopyFile` by about a 2.5:1 margin (Windows-specific code though, not what's above).

Answer (score 10):

Here is a complete program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    std::cout << std::ifstream(ac == 1? "foo": av[1]).rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: lol, I had never seen anyone use anything other than `argc` and `argv` as parameter names in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::filebuf` directly:

```
std::cout << std::filebuf{}.open("in.txt", std::ios_base::in);
```

Comment: why is there a new in your code? addressof would do nicely, I wager

Comment: You could just use `std::cout << std::filebuf().open("in.txt");`

Comment: Sadly, it is undefined behavior if `in.txt` doesn't exist but otherwise quite nice ;)

Comment: [`std::filebuf::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) has two mandatory arguments. You need a `std::ios::in` in there.

Comment: @Casey Completely slipped my mind. Thanks.

Comment: I think that makes `std::cout << std::ifstream("in.txt").rdbuf()` shorter overall, so my upvote goes to @DietmarKühl.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I forgot `open` returned a pointer so my bad. Also, how do the file streams prevent `filebuf::open` from opening on a non-existent file (and thus invoking undefined behavior). Do they do some system-specific operation to check if the file exists and if it doesn't, simply sets `failbit` (or in the case of `ofstream` creates the file)?

Comment: @0x499602D2: when the `std::ifstream` fails to open the file, the stream will have `std::ios_base::failbit` set. However, the `std::filebuf` does exist and you can get hold of a pointer to it. Using the `std::filebuf` returned from an `std::ifstream` which failed to open the file has to gracefully fail.

Comment: @Casey Actually mine is shorter when you take out the full qualification of the identifiers. But in any case, I'm fine with your giving the upvote to someone else.